# finding the shortest graph within parameters

Tags: python, graph-algorithm

```
def shortestPath(digraph, start, end, maxTotalDist, maxDistOutdoors, visited=[]):
    if not (digraph.hasNode(start) and digraph.hasNode(end)):
        raise ValueError('Start or end not in graph.')
    path = [str(start)]
    if start == end:
        return path
    shortest = None
    MinimumTotalDist = 0
    for node in digraph.childrenOf(start):
        if (str(node) not in visited): #avoid cycles
            visited = visited + [str(node)] #new list
            FirstStepDist = digraph.childrenOf(start)[node][0]
            FirstStepOutdoors = digraph.childrenOf(start)[node][1]
            newPath = shortestPath(digraph, node, end, maxTotalDist, maxDistOutdoors, visited)
            if newPath == None:
                continue
            TotalDist = int(FirstStepDist) + TotalDistance(digraph,newPath)
            TotalOutdoorDist = int(FirstStepOutdoors) + TotalOutdoorDistance(digraph,newPath)
            **if TotalOutdoorDist > maxDistOutdoors:
                continue**
            if (shortest == None or TotalDist < MinimumTotalDist):
                shortest = newPath
                MinimumTotalDist = TotalDist
    if shortest != None:
        path = path + shortest
    else:
        path = None

    if TotalDistance(digraph,path) <= maxDistOutdoors:
        return path
```

It's not giving me the correct answer.  It returns a valid path, yes.  However, the path it returns isn't the shortest path.  The problem is with the bold line where I skip the path if its total outdoor distance is greater than the constraint maxDistOutdoors, but I don't know how to change it.  When I remove that bold line I get the correct minimal paths, but if I need to have a check like that in there because I want to find minimal paths with total outdoor distance less than maxDistOutdoors.

I've tried print statements already and I'm about to give up.  I just don't understand why it's incorrect now.

Comment: I'm not sure why your code ends up incorrect.  However, are you aware that it is incredibly inefficient?  It looks to me like you are searching every possible non-cyclic path starting at the start node in order to find the shortest one.  There are much faster ways to do things.

Comment: I'm aware but I don't know how to code such a method.

But yeah, it's baffling me to no end why my if statement throws off some results.

Comment: For a simple shortest-path function take a look at http://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/. Might help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't return the shortest path possible because the algorithm you're using ([DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)) does not return the shortest path. Instead, try a [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)!

However, since you have some weight constraints (distance outdoors), you should check out [Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). You should find it pretty easy to integrate your constraints.